# Shortened titles for section, subsection, and subsubsection

Tags: sectioning

Latex is capable of having a shortened header for the long chapter title using `\chaptermark{<shortened title>}`, which is similar to using the optional argument to `\chapter[<ToC entry>]{<title>}` to display a different `ToC` entry to what is displayed in the main document.

Whilst there exists a similar thing for `\section`, it seems that  titles for `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` are not displayed in the page headers.

It has be mentioned that it is rare for documents to use titles below `\section` in a running head.  Is this a design decision of Latex ?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}

%% 13x21 cm Page Size
\geometry{ paperwidth=13cm, paperheight=21cm,
  %textwidth=12cm,  textheight=20cm, % This is not needed
  margin=8mm, includehead}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{This is an introduction to some topic}
\chaptermark{Introduction}

\section[Section Heading]{This is a section discussion about this and that}
\lipsum[1-30]

\subsection[Subsection Heading]{This is a subsection discussion about here and there}
\lipsum[1-30]

\subsubsection[Subsubsection Heading]{This is a subsubsection discussion about wear and tear}
\lipsum[1-30]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: you could make an educated guess and then search. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/397193/2388

Comment: `\sectionmark` for `\section`, `\subsectionmark` for `\subsection` etc. And some classes like the [KOMA-Script class](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) or [memoir](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) also provide extended optional arguments for `\chapter` etc. to distinguish between ToC entry and page header.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: It's vanishingly rare that a document uses any title below `\section` in a running head.