# How to make text / section heading after chapter same space

Tags: report

How do I make the spacing between the chapter title and the text / section / whatever after it the same space ? I tried using this `\titlespacing\chapter{0pt}{50pt}{20pt}` but the text and section after the title still do not have the same spacing.

[image]

Comment: They look more-or-less the same to me. However, the different might be because of the font sizes and/or baselines of the elements you're showing. For example, `Test` has no descenders like `Background`; adding `\strut` to the title should correct for this. Also, `\section` is typically set in `\large`, so add `{\large\strut}` just before `Test.` I'm thinking you want all of this automated, right? Well, it's probably easier to just fix it manually.

Comment: @Werner I think the OP means same distance between chapter "label" to chapter title and chapter title to text or section following... (Not sure)

Comment: Your main claim does not seem to be correct. You may be confused by the fact that the word "Test" which follows the chapter-3 header is typeset at a different font size than the string "2.1 Recurrent Neural Networks" that follows the chapter-2 header. This may be verified by inserting the directive `\Large` before "Test" at the start of chapter 3. For sure, one might well argue that it would be improper (typographically speaking) not to adjust the spacing for the fact that a section-level header might occur after a chapter header.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be based on an incorrect premise.

Comment: I am thinking to vote to reopen this question because closed by a misunderstood of OP's request... It is clear for me that the OP asks for equality between (chapter header[word chapter] with chapter name) and (chapter title header with text/section/whatever). So the reason that closed as off-topic doesn't seems valid to me.  (Voting... Feel free to re-close if you thing I am wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Title Page
\title{}
\author{}

\def\reducespace{\vspace*{-15pt}}

\let\oldchapter\chapter
\makeatletter
\def\chapter{%
\@ifstar{\@Starred}{\@nonStarred}%
}
\def\@Starred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\GenericWarning{}{Warning: A starred chapter can not have parameters. I am going to ignore them!}\@StarredWith}%
{\@StarredWithout}%
}      
\def\@StarredWith[#1]#2{%
\oldchapter*{#2}\reducespace%
}
\def\@StarredWithout#1{
\oldchapter*{#1}\reducespace%
}
\def\@nonStarred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@nonStarredWith}%
{\@nonStarredWithout}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWith[#1]#2{%
\oldchapter[#1]{#2}\reducespace%
}
\def\@nonStarredWithout#1{%
\oldchapter{#1}\reducespace%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\chapter{Test Chapter 1}
text
\chapter{Test chapter 2}
\section{Section 1}
\end{document}
```

source: an old answer of mine here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380116/120578

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I once started with such `\def\chapter... ` thingies four years ago but soon learned that `xpatch` and `xparse` provide much better methods. `\@ifstar...` etc is getting tedious

Comment: thanks for reminding @ChristianHupfer... I will keep in mind... I still love old years :P