# \chapter* and titlesec

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I'm having a problem with titlesec's explicit option. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]{}
{#1}{0pt}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{hi there}

\end{document}
```

In this example code, we redefine the `\chapter` command. In my real example, I use the `explicit` option because I need to pass the title of the chapter to a complicated Tikz code. However, as it's written, the `\chapter*` of `\tableofcontents` doesn't display any heading at all.

The question is: how do you work titlesec when the explicit option is on, to allow the printing of starred chapters?

Comment: May be this answer for section can help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380116/120578 . You can use the same code for chapter instead and keep or not keep the old definition

Comment: You need to add an `\titleformat` command for the numberless chapters too. See the linked duplicate for an example.