# How to put an asterisk next to a section label?

Tags: sectioning

I want to add an asterisk to some section labels. This is often used to indicate that a section is optional, like so:

> 1.1*  Optional Section

Here is my solution :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}*}
\section{Optional Section}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\section{Required Section}

\end{document}
```

Will this solution cause any problems? Is there a better way to do it?

For my document, `thesection` is only used in section headings, so it will not cause problems with theorem numbering, etc. However, others may want to know how to fix that.

Comment: Hope this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450666/a-modified-section-command may helps you...

Comment: You might be interested in the `titlesec`  solution for ‘variants’: see `§4.3 Variants`, pp.12-13 of the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bernard mentioned in the comments, the solution is found in Section 4.3 of the `titlesec` documentation. Here is an example of the solution :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand{\secmark}{}
\newenvironment{advanced}
  {\renewcommand{\secmark}{*}}
  {}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\large\bfseries} % Format of the title
  {\thesection\secmark} % Label
  {1em} % Separation between label and title body 
        % (default = horizontal space, display = vertical space)
  {} % Code preceding the title

\begin{document}

\begin{advanced}
\section{Optional Section}
Content.    
\end{advanced}

\section{Required Section}
Content. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For people using KOMA-classes, one can do something like

```latex
\renewcommand{\sectionformat}{%
    \thesection%
    \texorpdfstring{\rlap{\ensuremath{^{\bstar}}}}{}%
    \autodot\enskip%
}%
```

Comment: Why the need for `\texorpdfstring`? Also, since this answer aims to be specific about some class, the question asks about the `section` number formatting, not `subsection`. You can definitely explain some code usage here.

Answer (score 1):

This should work with all classes. The idea is to call

```
\advanced\section
```

for the special sectional units (any level, so long as it's numbered).

How is it done? When `\advanced\section` is followed, the meaning of `\thesection` is saved and modified by adding `\advancedmarker` at the end. After the title is typeset, the meaning of `\thesection` is restored.

THe `\advancedmarker` command prints a zero width asterisk when printing the sectional title and in the table of contents, but a normal asterisk in all other situations.

Bonus feature: if one doesn't want the asterisk when `\ref` is used, it's sufficient to change the definition of `\advancedmarker` to

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\advancedmarker}{}
 {
  \bool_if:NT \__advanced_killwidth_bool { \makebox[0pt][l]{*} }
 }
```

and `\ref{test}` will not print any asterisk.

The complete code.

```
\documentclass{report}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\advanced}{mO{#3}m}
 {% #1 is a sectioning command
  % save the current meaning of \the<level>
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \__advanced_save: { the \cs_to_str:N #1 }
  % add \advancemarker
  \cs_set:cpn { the \cs_to_str:N #1 } { \__advanced_save: \advancedmarker }
  \bool_set_true:N \__advanced_killwidth_bool
  #1[#2]{#3}
  \bool_set_false:N \__advanced_killwidth_bool
  % reset \the<level> to the previous meaning
  \cs_set_eq:cN { the \cs_to_str:N #1 } \__advanced_save:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\advancedmarker}{}
 {
  \bool_if:NTF \__advanced_killwidth_bool { \makebox[0pt][l]{*} } { * }
 }

\bool_new:N \__advanced_killwidth_bool

\AddToHook{cmd/@starttoc/begin}{\bool_set_true:N \__advanced_killwidth_bool}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}

Beware that \ref{test} is a difficult section.

\section{This is a normal section}

\advanced\section{This is an optional advanced section}\label{test}

\section{This is a normal section}

\subsection{With a normal subsection}

\advanced\subsection{And an advanced subsection}

\subsection{And a normal subsection}

\advanced\chapter{A difficult chapter}

\end{document}
```

#### The TOC

[image]

#### The first chapter (standard)

[image]

#### The second chapter (advanced)

[image]