# Memoir: Decorate chapter/section/... with a star in title and TOC, but not \ref{}

Tags: sectioning, memoir

I'd like to be able to mark chapter/section/... with a star (i.e., "difficult/optional material"), but I consider the "*" as a decoration only, it should not affect references (if chapter 1 is optional, it is marked as such in the heading and in TOC, but it is still just chapter 1 for references).

The solution using xparse to [question 450666](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450666/a-modified-section-command/450681#450681) here is pretty close to what I'm looking for, but \ref{opt} produces "*1.2", I'd like plain "1.2". And I'd like to extend to chapter/section/subsection/... (I think that should be easy, once the basic mechanism is ironed out).

**Update:** The referenced partial solution to the problem (by @egreg) is:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\NewDocumentCommand{\optionalsection}{O{#3}om}{%
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\optasterisk\standardthesection}%
   \optzerotrue
   \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\section[#1]{#3}}{\section[#1][#2]{#3}}%
   \optzerofalse
   \renewcommand{\thesection}{\standardthesection}%
}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\standardthesection\thesection}

\NewDocumentCommand{\optasterisk}{}{%
   \ifoptzero\makebox[0pt][r]{*}\else*\fi
}
\newif\ifoptzero

\begin{document}

   \frontmatter

   \optzerotrue
   \tableofcontents*
   \optzerofalse

   \mainmatter
   \chapter{Test}

   \section[TOC title][Header title]{Main title}

   \optionalsection[TOC title opt][Header title opt]{Main title opt}\label{opt}

   This is a reference to \ref{opt}.

   \kant % to see the header title

   \end{document}
```

I'd like to extend this to \chapter, \subsection, ... (I believe that should be easy to manage). But I *dont* want the references to show up with "*", just titles and TOC.

As a comment says, yes, I do need hyperref. It is math-heavy text, several of the ams packages are loaded too.  In any case, I think I can fix any fallout from those; if not, I'll be back here ;-)

A short test including hyperref seems to work fine.

Comment: Please provide some example code others can work on. Otherwise this is a `please do this for me` question which is generally disliked around here. For example it is not clear from your words where that start should be shoed and where it should not be shown. Also not clear whether you are using `hyperref` or not as that often affects custom solutions involving the TOC