# Change font for the \paragraph command

Tags: fonts, sectioning, sections-paragraphs

If I add something like

```
\paragraph{Title} Paragraph text
```

to my LaTeX document, "Title" will have a bold font. I want to change it to `\textit`. How can I do it for `\paragraph{}` and `\paragraph*{}` commands without switching to another document class (maybe using `\renewcommand`)? I use the report class.

Comment: Your question is already answered by an existing thread: [Redefining commands in Latex (\section in particular)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/251912/2975). In your case use `\makeatletter\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}{-1em}{\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}}\makeatother`. If you, however, use a non-standard document class this solution will not work.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Thanks for the pointer, but I would not be able to come to the command, which you provided, using that answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load `titlesec` and add to your preamble:

```
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\itshape\mdseries}
```