# Capitalize first letter of words in chapter mark

Tags: fancyhdr, patching, xpatch, mfirstuc

I would like to capitalize the first letter of several words in the chapter and the chapter mark.
While text in the chapter itself is capitalized, in the chapter mark it is not.

Here is a MWE of my current code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mfirstuc,fancyhdr,lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{mainmatter}
    \chapter{\ecapitalisewords{some thing} with Text}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

How can I make `fancyhdr` work with `\ecapitalisewords` ?

[image]

EDIT:

I noticed that `\nouppercase` kills `\MakeUppercase`

```
\def\nouppercase##1{{\let\uppercase\relax\let\MakeUppercase\relax
      \expandafter\let\csname MakeUppercase \endcsname\relax##1}}%
```

which however is needed by `\ecapitalisewords` which uses

```
\def\@gls@makefirstuc#1{\MFUapplytofirst\mfirstucMakeUppercase{#1}}
\newcommand*{\mfirstucMakeUppercase}{\MakeUppercase}
```

I further notices, that `fancyhdr.sty`
defines `\chaptermark` with `\MakeUppercase`.

For this reason, I tried

```
 \documentclass{book}

 \usepackage{mfirstuc,fancyhdr,lipsum}




 \fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
 }
% 


\let\orgMakeUppercase\MakeUppercase

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\chaptermark}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\sectionmark}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@gls@makefirstuc}{\mfirstucMakeUppercase}{\orgMakeUppercase}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{mainmatter}
    \chapter{\ecapitalisewords{some thing} with Text}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

But without success, the chaptermark is this time ALL CAPITAL, meaning the patching did not seem to work to being with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your solution doesn't work is that `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` are redefined when you call `\pagestyle{mainmatter}`.
This happens because every page style created with `\fancypagestyle` also calls `\ps@fancy` when set, and this sets both `\chaptermark` and `\sectionmark` to something that uses `\MakeUppercase`.

To get rid of these `\MakeUppercase`s, you could add the lines (which I copied from your question)

```
\xpatchcmd{\chaptermark}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}%
\xpatchcmd{\sectionmark}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}%
```

to your document, right after calling `\pagestyle{mainmatter}`.

Adding these lines to the second argument of `\fancypagestyle` won't work because `\ps@fancy` is called last and would undo these patches. 
You could however patch the macro `\ps@mainmatter` that was created by `\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{…}` directly to include these lines.
Here's how that would/could go:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mfirstuc,fancyhdr,lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{% %% <- defines \ps@mainmatter
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}%
    \fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}%
}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
  \appto\ps@mainmatter{% %% <- appends to \ps@mainmatter
    \xpatchcmd{\chaptermark}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}%
    \xpatchcmd{\sectionmark}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{mainmatter} %% <- calls \ps@mainmatter
    \chapter{\ecapitalisewords{some thing} with Text}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image: chapter title]

[image: header]

---

#### Addendum:

You could also redefine `\ps@fancy` to remove all instance of `\MakeUppercase` there, but you're asking for the least invasive solution, and that probably wouldn't be it.
For completeness, though, here's a way to do that:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mfirstuc,fancyhdr,lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{% %% <- defines \ps@mainmatter
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}%
    \fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}%
    \fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}%
}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\newrobustcmd\exhaustivepatchcmd[3]{% %%<- patches as often as necessary
  \patchcmd{#1}{#2}{#3}{\exhaustivepatchcmd{#1}{#2}{#3}}{}%
}
\makeatletter
  \patchcmd{\ps@fancy}{\def\MakeUppercase{\uppercase}}{}{}{}
  \exhaustivepatchcmd{\ps@fancy}{\MakeUppercase}{\@firstofone}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{mainmatter}
    \chapter{\ecapitalisewords{some thing} with Text}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

*(I only define `\exhaustivepatchcmd` because manually calling `\patchcmd` three times feels wrong. I remove `\def\MakeUppercase{\uppercase}` because that instance of `\MakeUppercase` shouldn't be patched (and serves no purpose).)*

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would be this:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mfirstuc,fancyhdr,lipsum}

\fancypagestyle{mainmatter}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\thepage}
    \fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
    \fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
}
\newcounter{mychap}
\newcommand\mychapadd{\setcounter{mychap}{\value{chapter}}\stepcounter{mychap}}
\newcommand\mchapter[1]{\xdef\Arg{#1}\mychapadd\xdef\leftmark{Chapter~\themychap.\space\Arg}
\chapter{\Arg}}
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{mainmatter}
    \mchapter{\ecapitalisewords{this is} a test}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

This solution uses the command `\mchapter` but you could redefine the original \chapter command to do it even if it is a starred command etc. (See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380116/120578))

Comment: Thanks! is there also a less invasive method? I though the root of the problem is the `\nouppercase` macro, is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, but this is the way I thought when answering and now I have not the time to look for something else... May be another day will look about it again, or someone else could answer till then.