# Equation ref in toc

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, ref

I have the following code:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
    \usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}
    \usepackage[a4paper,top=2.50cm,bottom=2.50cm,left=2.50cm,right=2.50cm]{geometry}
    
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,commath}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{physics}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{color}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
    \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
    
    %hypersetup
    \hypersetup{
            unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
            pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
            pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
            pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
            pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
            pdftitle={Renormalization in quantum mechanics: two-dimensional delta-interaction as a case study},    % title
            pdfauthor={Me},     % author
            pdfsubject={Physics},   % subject of the document
            pdfcreator={Me},   % creator of the document
            pdfproducer={Me}, % producer of the document
            pdfkeywords={theorethical physics, quantum mechanics, renormalization, regularization, effective field theory}, % list of keywords
            pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new PDF window
            colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
            linktoc=page,
            linkcolor=blue,         % color of internal link
            citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
            filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
            urlcolor=red            % color of external links
        }


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
Here there's an equation
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
 \boldsymbol{F} = m\boldsymbol{a}
\end{equation}

\section{Meaning of \eqref{eq1}}
Bla bla...

\end{document}
```

What I'm trying to do is to remove the equation link only in the TOC. Someone can help me?

Comment: What about `\section[Meaning of (1)]{Meaning of \eqref{eq1}}` (if you don't use it for headers too)?

Comment: It works unless i change the equation numeration, so i was searching for an authomtic solution

Comment: `\makeatletter
\section[Meaning of (\protect\ref*{eq1})]{Meaning of \eqref{eq1}}
\makeatother
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer according to my comment and to an old answer of redefining the section command [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380116/120578)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
    \usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}
    \usepackage[a4paper,top=2.50cm,bottom=2.50cm,left=2.50cm,right=2.50cm]{geometry}
    
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,commath}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{physics}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{color}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
    \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
    
    %hypersetup
    \hypersetup{
            unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
            pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
            pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
            pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
            pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
            pdftitle={Renormalization in quantum mechanics: two-dimensional delta-interaction as a case study},    % title
            pdfauthor={Matteo Tagliazucchi},     % author
            pdfsubject={Physics},   % subject of the document
            pdfcreator={Matteo Tagliazucchi},   % creator of the document
            pdfproducer={Matteo Tagliazucchi}, % producer of the document
            pdfkeywords={theorethical physics, quantum mechanics, renormalization, regularization, effective field theory}, % list of keywords
            pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new PDF window
            colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
            linktoc=page,
            linkcolor=blue,         % color of internal link
            citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
            filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
            urlcolor=red            % color of external links
        }


\let\oldsection\section
\makeatletter
\def\msection{%
\@ifstar{\@Starred}{\@nonStarred}%
}
\def\@Starred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\GenericWarning{}{Warning: A starred section can not have optional parameters. I am going to ignore them!}\@StarredWith}%
{\@StarredWithout}%
}      
\def\@StarredWith[#1]#2{%
\oldsection*{#2}%
}
\def\@StarredWithout#1{
\oldsection*{#1}%
}
\def\@nonStarred{%
\@ifnextchar[%
{\@nonStarredWith}%
{\@nonStarredWithout}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWith[#1]#2{%
\newcommand\myeqref[1]{(\ref*{##1})}
\oldsection[#1]{#2}%
}
\def\@nonStarredWithout#1{%
\oldsection{#1}%
}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
Here there's an equation
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
 \boldsymbol{F} = m\boldsymbol{a}
\end{equation}

\msection[Meaning of \myeqref{eq1}]{Meaning of \eqref{eq1}}

Bla bla...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the hook `\pdfstringdefdisablecommands` of the hyperref-package for cranking out the case of LaTeX being in the situation of producing a PDF string for a bookmark or the like which will be evaluated/processed by the pdf-viewing program at the time of displaying the .pdf-file. This way you can get rid of hyperref's "Token not allowed in PDF string..."-warnings.

Besides this the definition/status of the token `\protect` can be checked for guessing whether LaTeX is about to produce normal text or LaTeX is about to process tokens that form a moving argument which will be written to external-file, e.g., the .toc-file underlying the table of contents.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
    \usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}
    \usepackage[a4paper,top=2.50cm,bottom=2.50cm,left=2.50cm,right=2.50cm]{geometry}
    
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,commath}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{physics}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{color}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
    \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
    
    %hypersetup
    \hypersetup{
        unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
        pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
        pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
        pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
        pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
        pdftitle={Renormalization in quantum mechanics: two-dimensional delta-interaction as a case study},    % title
        pdfauthor={Me},     % author
        pdfsubject={Physics},   % subject of the document
        pdfcreator={Me},   % creator of the document
        pdfproducer={Me}, % producer of the document
        pdfkeywords={theorethical physics, quantum mechanics, renormalization, regularization, effective field theory}, % list of keywords
        pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new PDF window
        colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
        linktoc=page,
        linkcolor=blue,         % color of internal link
        citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
        filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
        urlcolor=red            % color of external links
    }

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \newcommand\nolinkeqref[1]{%
    \textup{\tagform@{\ref*{#1}}}%
  }%
  \pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
    \def\nolinkeqref#1{(\ref*{#1})}%
    \def\eqref#1{(\ref*{#1})}%
  }%
}{%
  \@ifdefinable\nolinkeqref{%
    \let\nolinkeqref=\eqref
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section 1}
Here there's an equation
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
 \boldsymbol{F} = m\boldsymbol{a}
\end{equation}

\section{Meaning of \ifx\protect\relax\eqref{eq1}\else\nolinkeqref{eq1}\fi}
Bla bla...


\end{document}
```

***!!! Attention/Possible pitfalls when having referencing-commands within the arguments of sectioning commands: !!!***

1. In the question the desired behavior in case of using section-headings also for writing page-headers is not specified.

   Names of referencing labels require special attention in case the documentclass in use produces page headers in uppercase letters (via `\MakeUppercase`) or the like  for section-headings which contain referencing-commands: When creating the page-header, the letters forming the names of referencing-labels might get uppercased too, at a time when the referencing-command in question is not carried out yet which might lead to an attempt of referencing `EQ1` instead of `eq1` either (in case `EQ1` not being defined) yielding undefined reference or (in case `EQ1` being defined also)  yielding reference to the wrong referencing-label within page-headers of pages that belong to the section with the section-heading "Meaning of `\eqref{eq1}`".

   The [textcase](https://ctan.org/pkg/textcase) package might be of interest.
2. The behavior of the `\nameref`-command needs to be checked for the situation of referring to a section via `\mameref` whose name itself contains a referencing-command.
3. 1 and 2 need to be taken into account simultaneously in case a section-heading contains `\nameref`-reference to an other section-heading...